# Main Differences between android 1.x and 2.x

Tags: android

Can't find the answer for the long time. Can someone help me to find differences?

Answer (score 3):

[Android API levels](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html)

Click on a version for a changelog.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer. Many things have been changed up and updated and added throughout all of the various different releases.

[See here, for an overview of what happened with each release](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history)

[Another good breakdown of it.](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/android-versions-comparison)

[Current version spread.](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)